# java.lang.NumberFormatException when reading text from keyboard

Tags: numberformatexception

This program reads numbers from keyboard and sums it until user writes "total", but then I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

```
Boolean isTotal = false;
    int sum = 0;
    while(!isTotal)
    {
        java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = br.readLine();
        if(s=="total")
        {
            isTotal = true;
        }
        if(!isTotal)
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: What numbers did you type on the keyboard? At which point is the Exception thrown?

Comment: when i type total

Comment: Does isTotal become true after that? Try printing s or setting a breakpoint to see its value.  By the way, you should compare strings using equals()

Comment: equals() helped

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boolean isTotal = false;
int sum = 0;
while(!isTotal)
{
    java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = br.readLine();
    if(s.equals("total"))
    {
        isTotal = true;
    }
    if(!isTotal)
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(s);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```